# SSRS report server project template

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2017

Quick question.  How do I  create a new SSRS project, i.e. i wish to  start a new project with New -->  Project

and choose from Installed -->  Templates --> Business Intelligence

and then select Report Server Project as project type.

I am working from VS 2017 and have SQL Server 2012 installed.

I just don't have the templates installed to choose the project type.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS and SQL Server Tools are always one major version in arrears of the Visual Studio release cycle. I would advise you to use VS2012 to target SQL Server 2012|2014. VS2017 will create a newer version of .rdl files that is not backward compatible. You will need to install a compatible version of SSRS locally to get your templates to show in VS2017.